# how to show separate column unique values with SQL GROUP BY clause

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Alright, I can't bash my head at this anymore tonight. Thought I would pose the question. Maybe there's a simple answer I have not come across yet.

I have a number of related tables in PHPMyAdmin: pubtopics, pubtypes, and pubtitles.

Pubtitles is the main table (table 1), pubtopics is a simple list assigning a number to a topic (table 2), and pubtypes is another simple list assigning a number to a publication type (table 3).

I'm trying to create a page that lists every publication by type (list of all pubs in table 3), but also shows the multiple topics (table 2) that may be assigned to a unique pubtitle (table 1), and have each of those topics (table 2) link to publications listed by that topic.

The data for pubtopics looks something like this:

[pubtopics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpE8U.png)

What I'm looking for is a line like this:

June 15, 2016 | Comparative Data Report | Education | Fiscal Affairs

Where the date is a link, the pub type is a link, and each of the concatenated issues is a unique link.

When I try to list all the publications for a specific publication **type**, all I can generate so far is either a list with multiple duplicate entries (because one may address several topics). I've tried group_concat and group by, but that doesn't allow me to have an individual link for each topic.

I've played around with explode and arrays, but it's a bit beyond my know-how. Any brilliant solutions?

Code looks like:

```
elseif (isset($_GET['type'])) {
  $var3_getDisplay4 = $_GET['type'];
  $query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT

  DATE_FORMAT(publicationsnew.date, '%%Y') AS archive,
  DATE_FORMAT(publicationsnew.date, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS pubdate,

  pub_type.number AS typelink,
  pub_type.type AS pubtype,

  GROUP_CONCAT(categories.category_name ORDER BY categories.category_name SEPARATOR ' | ') AS category,

  categories.category_id AS catlink,

  publicationsnew.title,
  publicationsnew.author,
  publicationsnew.imagelink,
  publicationsnew.description

FROM 

pub_cat

LEFT JOIN publicationsnew ON (pub_cat.pub_id = publicationsnew.pub_id)
LEFT JOIN categories ON (pub_cat.category_id = categories.category_id)
LEFT JOIN pub_type ON (publicationsnew.type = pub_type.number)

  WHERE pub_type.number = %s

  GROUP BY publicationsnew.pub_id

  ORDER BY publicationsnew.date DESC",



  GetSQLValueString($var3_getDisplay4, "text"));
```

and in the body:

```
<?php do { ?>

      <h2><a href="test.php?archive=<?php echo $row_getDisplay['archive']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['pubdate']; ?></a> | <a href="test.php?type=<?php echo $row_getDisplay['typelink']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['pubtype']; ?></a> | 




     <a href="test.php?topic=<?php echo $row_getDisplay['catlink']; ?>">

     <?php echo $row_getDisplay['category']; ?>

     </a>

     </h2>
      <p class="pubtitle"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['title']; ?></p>

  <?php echo ($row_getDisplay['author']); ?>  

  <?php echo ($row_getDisplay['imagelink']); ?>

   <div class="pubdescription"><?php echo ($row_getDisplay['description']); ?></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>



     <hr>

   <?php } while ($row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay)); ?>
```

Burned out for the day. To be continued...

Comment: Also, read up on table aliases. More readable, and less typing!

Comment: I inherited this system with tables aliases, and wasn't really a fan. The aliases were not really very descriptive, and caused more confusion than efficiency...

Doesn't really help with the problem I'm having either...

Comment: Well, making your code more readable (for others) might mean that those others are more inclined to help.